# Creating a Google Maps application

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I have been behind the 8-ball all quarter for my class some how I am supposed to be able to do this in 4 hours.

**My Assignment**

The purpose of this assignment is to utilize a map to display a route using overlays/polylines.

The goal of this assignment is to enhance the assignment from week 5 (web service to retrieve directions) to display the retrieved directions as a route on a map in addition to a list of steps.

You are required to write a single application that runs on a tablet configuration (Nexus 10 or some variation of a 10 inch screen tablet)

**User Interface Requirements**

The left side of the screen (ListView, left-pane) will contain the interface outlined in the week 5 assignment. A user can enter a source and destination and retrieve a list of directions based on that input. So, the interface is a couple textfields, a button, and a list.

The right side of the screen (right-pane, details view) will contain a Map that displays the directions as a segmented line (route). The map and route gets updated/displayed after the directions are retrieved (selection of the button). An initial map should be displayed with some default settings when the screen is first loaded.

**Other Requirements**

The Map should display the entire route (start and end point) at the appropriate zoom level (depending on the distance). The correct map type should also be used depending on the distance.

You are required to use a Marker to display the starting point and ending destination.

You are required to use the MapFragment class.

You are required to use API V2 from Google Maps and the Google Play Services API.

You are required to use the XMLPullParser class for parsing the XML.

This application will look very similar to the Google maps application that is used on the web (with a lot less detail, no zooming in out of the map, etc), concerning the route displayed, and left pane to enter source / destination and direction list.

Using Android Studio I have tried Creating an Application using the Map Activity, but it creates and application that will not compile and it looks like it wants me to use Google Keys.  I can't hand in an assignment that requires Keys assigned to me.

I already have 4 hours into this and I can't even get started.  I read that v3 of googles map API's doesn't need keys, but I can't find anything that tells me how to use them and Android Studio Doesn't seem to give you options as to what to download and use.

I really need help.

Comment: What I have learned with this assignment.  Android Studio does not automatically show Googles API's unless you click the Show more at the bottom of the screen.  Android Studio will create and compile an application that is not supported by the device (At least for Google play services).  I still have not figured out how to use v3, but the assignment went in.